# GKE preemptible pools

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We run a number of batch jobs daily. For cost reasons we run mostly on preemptible VMs, via an in-house VM management system configured to use preemptible VMs first and failover to regular VMs.

We'd like to use GKE + pools of preemptible VMs instead. To the best of my knowledge, this is currently unsupported. Does it happen to be on the product roadmap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for creating a cluster or node pool with preemptible VMs was just added to Google Container Engine (see the [release notes from October 17th](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes#october_17_2016)).

Run `gcloud beta container node-pools create --preemptible NAME` to create a new node pool with preemptible VMs.

Comment: Thanks! You guys rock! Our use-case is a simple controller / workers setup. To make the preemptible feature maximally effective we'd like to run the master on regular pools and the workers with affinity for preemptible pools. This seems doable, the challenge is how to setup a job with a controller / worker setup. Best documentation we could find is http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/#single-job-starts-controller-pod, which suggests a DIY approach, but without going into specifics. Are we on the right track, or is there some extra kube magic we're missing? :)

Comment: There isn't any magic here. It is DIY.  One option is to create a "Jobs" that runs the controller in a pod, and have the controller start the worker pods, and delete the controller pods when the job is done.

Comment: How about using `nodeSelector`?